# Simulate thread local variables

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-local

I want to simulate thread local variables for non static members, something like this :

```
template< typename T, unsigned int tNumThread >
class ThreadLocal
{
private:

protected:
    T mData[tNumThread];

    unsigned int _getThreadIndex()
    {
        return ...; // i have a threadpool and each thread has an index from 0 to n
    }

public:
    ThreadLocal() {};
    ~ThreadLocal() {};

    T& operator ->()
    {
        return mData[_getThreadIndex()];
    }
    ...
};
```

But the problem is that number of thread will be determined at runtime and i must allocate `mData` from heap.

I want to know is there any way to don't use allocation from heap and use regular array like above?

Comment: Compilers normally provide extended syntax to do this.  You need to mention your compiler name and version.

Comment: @HansPassant If i remember correctly in VS we have `_declspec(thread)` and in c++11 `threadlocal` but they work on `Static` variables and i want `ThreadLocals` for `non-static` variables

Comment: you cannot use this pattern `T mData[tNumThread];` if sizeof(T) < 64 or 128. Otherwise you create a big bottleneck caused by MESI protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Each thread has it's own stack, and remember stack frames are popped (or can be thought of as popping) when a function returns.

This is why we have "stackless python", because 1 stack (what python needs) and multiple threads do not play nice (see global interpreter lock)

You could put it in main, that will last, but remember C(++) wants to know all the sizes at COMPILE TIME, so if the thread count changes (isn't fixed AT COMPILE TIME) there's no way to know this.

What you really want is something not in main, but this wouldn't be a template (in the number) because that number cannot be known at compile time.

There is a stack allocate function (like malloc) that GCC provides, but I cannot find it, it is good to avoid using it though because then optimisations actually work.

Equally don't underestimate your CPUs read-ahead abilities and GCCs optimisation, putting the array on the heap isn't bad.

Interesting read with good pictures but unfortunately only distantly related to the topic:
http://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/malloc.html

Comment: Agree with last paragraph but if i want use this class in `Nodes` of data structure(eg in linked list) i have two allocation for each node. So there is no way to avoid allocation in heap :(

Comment: @MohammadRB so? Also that's not thread local if every thread has it's own instance. I forget the name but now I get the question. new is great for lots of allocations that happen once (if your objects are constantly being deleted and re-created, you may want a pool), trust in new and the optimiser, they are advanced, production-quality routines made to be used.

Comment: @MohammadRB why didn't I get the tick? Also have you thought about using C++11s thread_local? Or rather than having all the copies together, maybe create a copy in each thread and add it to a "registry"

Comment: see my comment in my question. I want to have `ThreadLocal` variables that aren't static. `C++11s thread_local` work only on static variables. i don't understand this: 'maybe create a copy in each thread and add it to a "registry"'

Comment: @MohammadRB these Ts belong to a thread, not to a registry (your threadlocal thing is a list of these Ts, not a registry, a list) and threads just.... access there T through it. Why not create a T in thread-local (so it blongs in every sense to the thread) and REIGSTER is with a list (pass a T* to where the thread's local is to a registry, have the registry __register__ it under a thread ID) Remember to do access locks and stuff, this is actually a frowned upon way of doing it, thread locals should be local to a thread. But I am assuming you have your reasons.

Comment: You say that i create a `thread-local T` and add it to a list with a key that is Thread id? what is the benefit of doing this over `thread-local`? (maybe i don't understand your aim)yet every thing is related to `thread-local` and static variables.

Comment: @MohammadRB I just want the tick :P If you don't understand it really is best to go read up on C++11s thread local, I'm not going to teach you that here in the comments. Please accept my answer ^.^

Answer (score 0):

I suggest:

```
std::unordered_map<std::thread::id, T, stackalloc> myTLS;
```

Either you gobally lock around all accesses, or you prepare population in advance and access it read only later.

You can use it in combination with a stack allocator.

```
typedef short_alloc<pair<const thread::id, T>, maxthrds> stackalloc;
```

https://howardhinnant.github.io/stack_alloc.html

If you want another solution, here you can do:

```
struct Padder
{
    T t;
    char space_[128 - sizeof(T)];  // if sizeof(T) >= 128 just don't include the padding.
};

std::array<Padder, maxthreads> myTLS;
```

For MESI bottleneck-free access.
You'll have to care about tracking your threads with their own index in this array, with this method.